# You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to post without a default; we can't do that ,Как решить проблему?

Tags: django

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import reverse

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=30,db_index=True,default='zero')
    sometext=models.CharField(max_length=50,db_index=True,default='zero')
    tags=models.ManyToManyField('Tag',blank=True, related_name='posts',default='zero')
    date_pub=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.title)


class Tag(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50,default='zero')
    sometext=models.CharField(max_length=50,default='zero' )

    def _str_(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.title)
```

если я добавляю default к date_pub уже другая ошибка появляется:

```
foundation.Post.date_pub: (fields.E160) The options auto_now, auto_now_add, and default are mutually exclusive. Only one of these options may be present.
```

Если нужны ещё какие то файлы пишите в комментарии ,миграцию делаю чтобы сделать отношение ManyToMany. 
Как решить проблему не представляю, django используется 2.x

Comment: при default='' ничего не меняется.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37356512/11301070

Comment: Попробуйте удалить файл миграции. В коде криминала вроде нет

Comment: Хотя меня немного смущает строковый default у m2m связи. Разве так можно?